# How to encrypt data with RSA private key (not normal signing) in Python?

Tags: python, rsa, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I want to make RSA encryption with private key (not normal signing), but PyCryptodome seems not be able to do it.

The reason I need to do it with private key is, I need to get the same results as from a Java program not written by me, which wrongly uses javax.crypto.Cipher and private key to sign messages...

```java
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

...

String deviceKey = "MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC...";
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec localPKCS8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(deviceKey).getBytes("UTF-8"));
PrivateKey localPrivateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(localPKCS8EncodedKeySpec);

byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest("test".getBytes());
Cipher localCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
localCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, localPrivateKey);
String sign = new String(Base64.encode(localCipher.doFinal(hash)));
```

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

...

deviceKey = 'MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC...'
privateKey = RSA.importKey(deviceKey)
hash = SHA256.new('test'.encode()).digest()
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(privateKey)
sign = b64encode(signer.encrypt(hash))
```

Result of the Java program:

- Hash: 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
- Sign: k8y6zMfl0KVuQWWOmRxieXF1aH0dpVUX......(always the same)

Result of my Python script:

- Hash: 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
- Sign: GfLVqZDnu5aLHHbi0tM5OtCBEVKKRcjW......(it changes every time)

Answer (score 2):

You don't use private keys to encrypt data.

- A private key can *sign* data, which can be *verified* by the matching public key.
- A public key can *encrypt* data, which can be *decrypted* by the matching private key.

If what you really want is to sign your hash, instead of using the `encrypt` function, you should use the `sign` function.

So, instead of

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
PKCS1_v1_5.new(privateKey).encrypt(hash)
```

you might want to try

```
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15
pkcs1_15.new(privateKey).sign(hash)
```

I wrote a little [blog post](https://blog.epalm.ca/signing-and-verifying-with-rsa-keys/) about signing/verifying using pycryptodome, if you want to take a look.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but who wrote that Java program doesn't. I want to get the same results as from it...

Comment: OP specifically asked about encrypting with the private key, and not about normal signing